# Interactively deselect selected cell with swipe back gesture

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

In apps such as Settings, when you tap on a cell which pushes a screen, then you swipe back from the left of the screen, you can see the deselection of the selected cell’s background color fading, and it's fully interactive - if you swipe half way then swipe back the selected background view returns to full opacity.

In my app, I haven't changed any of the default behavior, and when I swipe from the left to go back, the selected cell background color remains completely opaque until the swipe gesture is completed, and then it quickly fades to deselect it.

How can one implement the interactive deselection of cells via the swipe to go back gesture?

Comment: Is it clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear method on UITableViewController you are looking for ?

Comment: clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is by default set to YES. I have not changed it to NO. Changing it to NO will never fade it to white - it will remain selected at all times until you programmatically deselect it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To enable interactive deselection in iOS 11 and newer, you can use `UITableViewController` because it implements it for you, or you can implement it by animating the deselection alongside the transition coordinator, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedIndexPath) {
        if (self.transitionCoordinator) { 
            [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) { 
                [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES]; 
            } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) { 
                 if (context.cancelled) { 
                     [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; 
                 } 
            }]; 
        } else { 
             [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:animated]; 
        }
    }
}
```

And in Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if let coordinator = transitionCoordinator {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
                self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
            }) { context in
                if context.isCancelled {
                    self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

A similar implementation works with `UICollectionView`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
        if let coordinator = transitionCoordinator {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
                self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }, completion: { context in
                if context.isCancelled {
                    self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
                }
            })
        } else {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It seems as though the `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` might actually be getting called by `viewDidAppear:` rather than `viewWillAppear:` The change only happens once the transition is completely over and if you cancel the interactive transition it does not happen at all (if it was in `viewWillAppear:`, it would). This looks like a `UIKit` bug as the docs clearly state it should be getting called in `viewWillAppear:`

Put the following line of code into `viewWillAppear:` and you will get the exact behavior you are looking for, I just tried it. This is probably the exact behavior that property triggers, just in the wrong method.

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! I shall file a bug report and ship it off to Apple.

Comment: @Joey Did Apple ever resolve the radar you posted, or could you post it on OpenRadar? :)

Comment: @hhanesand No, the report is still open, it's rdar://17041392 but I didn't add it to OpenRadar. I bet others have it reported there already, this question was asked two years ago. ;)

Comment: @Joey Realized that :) , but thanks anyways, I guess that was the expected outcome when dealing with Apple's bug reporter.

Answer (score 0):

Using Private API (unsafe - Apple will reject your app)

```objectivec
#import <objc/message.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    ((void (*)(id, SEL, BOOL, id))objc_msgSend)(self.collectionView, sel_registerName("_deselectAllAnimated:notifyDelegate:"), YES, nil);
}
```